# how to open and read .alarms files in MIMIC II

Tags: mimic-iii

I have a question about the .alarms files in MIMIC-II. I am not familiar with the .alarms file type and I could not find information about this on the internet. Could someone let me know how best to open and read these .alarms files? I have tried different programs but always only some of the texts are shown correctly.

Comment: I get several hits [Googling for '.alarms file type mimic'](https://www.google.com/search?q=.alarms+file+type+mimic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

Answer (score 1):

The rdann function from the wfdb toolbox can be used to open those files.